# Android - Fill string array with urls

Tags: java, android

I have a url "yyyyyyy.com/test.txt", which is a text file.
It contains urls of .mp3 audios.

```
yyyyyyy.de/1.mp3
yyyyyyy.de/2.mp3
yyyyyyy.de/3.mp3 //exactly like that
```

My intention was to read each line of this text file and store it in an array like

```
urls[0]=yyyyyyy.de/1.mp3
urls[1]=yyyyyyy.de/2.mp3 ...
```

this.

```
String[] urls;
int i=0;

Random rand;
int min=0;
int max=5; // I have 6 Urls in the text file
int randomNum;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  rand = new Random();

    randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min; //generates integer between 0-5
    try {
        // Create a URL for the desired page
        URL url = new URL("yyyyy.de/test.txt"); //My text file location

        // Read all the text returned by the server
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new     InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String str;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
           urls[i]=str;
           i++;
        }
        in.close();
       } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      } catch (IOException e) {
     }


    boolean isPLAYING = false;

    if (!isPLAYING) {
        isPLAYING = true;
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mp.setDataSource(urls[randomNum]);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    } else {
        isPLAYING = false;

    }

}
```

I have already add in Manifest.xml the android:permission.
I don't know where the problem is...the app closes itself and tells me
that this line "  `mp.setDataSource(urls[randomNum]);`" is wrong

Here LogCat : http://textuploader.com/5iw5b
Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Please post error log

Comment: Two things: 1) generate `randomNum` after you create the `urls` array so you can initialize it have a value between (0 to `urls.size()`). That way you don't need to change the value of `max` in your program when you add and remove lines in you file. 2) Try debugging through your program so you can see how many entries are in `urls`. If you don't know how to debug then put a print statement in instead.

Comment: From the documentation, the main Exceptions from `void setDataSource (String path)` are: `IllegalStateException`, `IOException`, `IllegalArgumentException` and `SecurityException`. You have to give us a LogCat error log, or some additional information for us to help you with. Also, when you access the URL, what is the reply the server gives you? Binary, text encoded, etc? The mime may break your app, giving you unexpected results (such as a 300 HTTP reply)

Comment: http://textuploader.com/5iw5b here I uploaded the error log @Dr.Nitpick 1) thanks 2) didn't get it, I tried to use Log.d to see the mistake...but I can't find this output in the Console/Logcat

Comment: please [edit] your question to include the logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array is `NULL`

put this code after `super.onCreate`

`urls=new String[max]`

**Update 3:**

try this:

```
ArrayList<String> urls=new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        // Create a URL for the desired page
        URL url = new URL("yyyyy.de/test.txt"); //My text file location

        // Read all the text returned by the server
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new     InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String str;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            urls.add(str);
        }
        in.close();
       } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      } catch (IOException e) {
     }

Log.i("test","url count="+urls.size());


    boolean isPLAYING = false;

    if (!isPLAYING) {
        isPLAYING = true;
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            int randomPos = new Random().nextInt(urls.size());
            mp.setDataSource(urls.get(randomPos));
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    } else {
        isPLAYING = false;

    }

}
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but it doesn't work either..same

Comment: may I have your Skype ?(If you have..) http://textuploader.com/5ibnx it highlighs the line with "int randomPos"

Comment: No i don't have Skype. I think problem is in the your source url. the path "yyyyy.de/test.txt"  dose not have any line or there is a problem in reading from url. i add a log in the update 3. try it and check the new log.